# How to omit processing of an Item() if it has already been seen by spider in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to remove duplicate business_names during a spider crawl. However, I still see duplicate business_names.

I tried if x != item['business_name'] continue with parsing.

What I want is that if a business_name doesn't already exist then parse it, if not then delete from list or skip query result.

Instead, the code below ignores my if statement; Here is what I have so far.

```
class Item(scrapy.Item):
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()
    phone_number = scrapy.Field()

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        for business in response.css('div.info'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
            for x in item['business_name']:
                if (x != item['business_name']):
                    if item['business_name']:
                        item['website']  = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                        if item['website']:
                            item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
                            yield item
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are seeing this behaviour is a problem of scope. You set `item['business_name'] =` to a the results of `.extract()` which is always a list (even if there is only one successful css.tag.

Then the code iterates over `item['business_name']` and checks if each element of the list is `=! item['business_name']`

Turns out, that will always be `True`.

It is equivalent to doing the following:

```
numbers = [1, 2 , 3, 4]
for x in numbers:
    if x != numbers:
        print(x)

#output
1
2
3
4
```

Instead, initialize a list outside of the for loop and check if value is in that list. For instance, something to the effect of:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for business in response.css('div.info'):
        seen_business_names = []
        item = Item()
        item['business_name'] = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
        for x in item['business_name']:
            if (x not in seen_business_names):
                if item['business_name']: # not sure why this is here unless it is possible you are extracting empty strings
                    item['website']  = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                    if item['website']:
                        item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
                        seen_business_names.append(x)
                        yield item
```

I don't have access to your html file, so I can't guarantee that above code will work, but the behavior you are facing would be expected based on the code you provided in original post.

Side note: The list in the solution above will only be preserved for each call to the `parse` step. In other words, for each start_url passed to `parse`.  If you want to ensure that one and only one `business_name` is extracted GLOBALLY for any page passed to `parse` during the life of the Spider class, we could maintain a list in class definition and check against it in the same way we did locally to `parse`. Consider:

```
class Item(scrapy.Item):
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()
    phone_number = scrapy.Field()

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    #new code here
    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_business_names = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for business in response.css('div.info'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('span[itemprop="name"]::text').extract()
            for x in item['business_name']:
                #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names
                if (x not in self.seen_business_names):
                    if item['business_name']:
                        item['website']  = business.css('div.links  a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                        if item['website']:
                            item['phone_number'] = business.css('div.phones.phone.primary::text').extract()
                            #new code here, call to self.seen_business_names 
                            self.seen_business_names.append(x)
                            yield item
```

Cheers!

Comment: i get `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'settings'`

Comment: i still see duplicate business names in the csv file.

Comment: Without looking at the source HTML there isn't much more I can do. I'm assuming your css.tag strings are valid. I can't test against anything on my end

Comment: i do see minor improvements, but ill make adjustments thank you so much, i will mark as an answer